# Index out of range in dataGridView for Selectionchanged listener

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataGridView which uses some text fields to fill its rows. I've also added a SelectionChange listener for the DataGridView. The problem happens on the listener when a new row is added to DataSource which states: "Index out of range error". Below is the code I used to fill a list of ParamsObject which has three properties and set by text fields. If the user enters values into text fields and clicks a button, a new row will be added to list.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("name");
        dt.Columns.Add("level");
        dt.Columns.Add("summary");

        List<ParamObject> param = GetParameters();
        foreach (var info in param)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["name"] = info.Name;
            row["level"] = info.Level;
            row["summary"] = info.Summary;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        dataGrid.DataSource = dt;
        dataGrid.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
        dataGrid.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
        dataGrid.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

The error occures in the first line of selection listener.

```
public void dataGridResult_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedRowsCount = _MainForm.dataGridResult.SelectedRows[0];
        string name = Convert.ToString(selectedRowsCount.Cells[0].Value);
        int lod = Convert.ToInt16(Convert.ToString(selectedRowsCount.Cells[1].Value));
    }
```

Comment: You are making an assumption there is a selected row on a grid on another form.

Comment: It's the same grid which is filled in other form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this line of code to check whenever rows aren't empty do something and it works.

```
void dataGridResult_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_MainForm.dataGridResult.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            var selectedRowsCount = _MainForm.dataGridResult.SelectedRows[0];
            string name = Convert.ToString(selectedRowsCount.Cells[0].Value);
    }
```